# How to start Cygwin's NFS server in read-write mode?

Tags: nfs, cygwin, readwrite

Installed Cygwin's NFS server. It works. But I can't make it allow writing to the filesystem. Why does it fail?

Server:

```
$ cat /etc/exports
#/ 10.99.98.2(rw,no_root_squash)
/cygdrive/c/foranevia *(rw,no_squash_root,anon_uid=0,anon_gid=0,no_subtree_check)
```

Client:

```
root@vi-notebook:/mnt# mount wpc:/cygdrive/c/foranevia nfs
root@vi-notebook:/mnt# mkdir nfs/qqq
mkdir: cannot create directory `nfs/qqq': Read-only file system
```

**Update**: Fixed configuration line to `/cygdrive/c/foranevia *(rw,no_root_squash)` and now it seems to work, although not all hosts can mount until I explicitly list them in `/etc/exports`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `/etc/exports` for newlines.

Also try to explicitly specify IP addresses that can write (`*` can fail)